# Unable to fix AxiosError: socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I 'm trying to send a get request using axios 1.6:

```
try {

  const response = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url,
    responseType: "stream",
  });

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)

}
```

It used to work before but now there is this annoying err I can 't find a fix for:

> AxiosError: socket hang up at AxiosError.from...

I tried to add some more option but it does 't work anymore!!

```
const response = await axios({
  method: "get",
  url,
  responseType: "stream",
  proxy: false,
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
  }),
  timeout: 60000,
});
```

How can we fix this ?

Comment: `It used to work before` ... before what? Is `AxiosError: socket hang up at AxiosError.from...` the WHOLE error, or is there some useful information in `...`

Comment: Have you recently changed the `url` or did some re-routing perhaps?